# Styling Buttons in AlertDialog, Android 2.3

Tags: android, android-layout, android-alertdialog

I know it is doable with Dialog. But that would be nice to achieve this with AlertDialog. Code so far

```
<resources>
<style name="MyTheme">
    <!-- some code -->
    <item name="android:buttonBarStyle">@style/CustomButtonBarStyle</item>
    <item name="android:borderlessButtonStyle">@style/CustomDialogButtonStyle</item>

    <!-- Working for Android 4+ -->
    <item name="android:alertDialogStyle">@style/CustomAlertDialogStyle</item>
    <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/CustomAlertDialogStyle</item>
    <!-- Does nothing: -->
    <!-- item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/CustomDialogButtonStyle</item -->
</style>

<style name="CustomAlertDialogStyle">
    <!-- making dialog transparent -->
</style>

<style name="CustomDialogButtonStyle">
    <item name="android:textColor">#000</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/button_drawable</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomButtonBarStyle">
    <item name="android:background">@null</item>
    <item name="android:dividerPadding">0dp</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

I'v spent a lot of time in google and found nothing. Now I want to know is that even possible. Thank you.

**UPD:**
Since I'm using DialogFragment I can style button programmatically.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    ((AlertDialog) getDialog()).getButton(Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setBackgroundColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
}
```

But I still have no idea, is it possible to apply style to it.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just make a custom dialog? It isn't hard and it will give you a lot of flexibility in styling.

First, you'll make an xml layout with your buttons styled how ever you want, then just set the `contentView` of the dialog to your xml file. You can access your new buttons by id.

[Here's a really good, simple tutorial about it.](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/)

Comment: Yes, I know how to do that. But I think using AlertDialog is much more clear and simple. If it is possible, I'd like to know how to. And if it is not, I'd like to know that either.

Comment: I don't think there is much we can do to customize the buttons of alert dialog. Creating a custom dialog seems the only way.